# How to setup IP alias on bridged interface in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, bridge

How do I setup an IP alias on a bridge (br0) device on Ubuntu ?

If I wait for br0 to come up and then do

```
/sbin/ifconfig br0:0 192.168.10.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

then it works fine.

If however I add the following to my /etc/network/interfaces file, it does not work and the network fails to start:

```
auto br0:0
iface br0:0 inet static
   address 192.168.10.1
   netmask 255.255.255.0
```

At the moment, I have a script in /etc/network/if-up.d/bridge_alias that does this as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "${LOGICAL}" == "br0" ] && [ "${PHASE}" = "post-up" ]; then
        echo -n "Starting br0:0 ... "
        /sbin/ifconfig br0:0 192.168.10.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
        echo "Done!"
fi
```

What is the right way of doing this though, just using the OS network config files ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way you can do that is from ifconfig (or maybe ip addr add, but i haven't checked it against bridges).
if-up.d is okay, but i recommend you use post-up in interfaces, like:

```
auto br0:0  
  iface br0:0 inet static  
  address 192.168.10.1  
  netmask 255.255.255.0  
  post-up /sbin/ifconfig br0:0 192.168.10.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

You can repeat post-up as much times as you want.

Comment: Thanks - didn't realise I could do that in a post-up command

Answer (score 2):

Here is something I'm using, works in Debian 8 and Ubuntu 16.03:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto br1 
iface br1 inet static
    bridge_ports eth1 
    address  172.17.17.1
    netmask  255.255.255.0
    network  172.17.17.0
    broadcast 172.17.17.255
    post-up /usr/sbin/dhcpd 

auto br1:1 
iface br1:1 inet static
    address 172.17.17.2
    netmask  255.255.255.0
    network  172.17.17.0
    broadcast 172.17.17.255
```